# move micro SD card to another phone

Tags: external-sd

I have recently moved all my applications from my Samsung ACE 5830 to Micro SD card.
As a next step i am trying to figure out move all my phon esettings to the SD card.
In short, what i am looking at is :

1)I want everything to be stored on the Micro SD card.
2) When i buy a new Samsung or any other Android phone, I just move the Micro SD card to new phone and it should behave like my old phone  with aal its settings and applications intact.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no way of doing this directly.  However you have a few options:

- Enable Google's backup (`Settings -> Privacy`). It will sync your settings and app list to the cloud, as well as any app data for apps that support it.
- If you're rooted, use [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).  It can save all your apps and data, and you could put the backup on your SD card.  You won't want to restore the data for system apps between two different phones though, since they're unlikely to be entirely compatible.